# When installing a program with wine, which directory is C:\ when finished installing?

Tags: wine, msi

I tried installing Ableton Live 10 trial with wine. It is an MSI file called  Setup.msi. I executed the file by using:

```
wine msiexec /i Setup.msi
```

Everything worked. When it finished installing, where is the C:\Program Files directory located?

Edit: I recently uninstalled windows and installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux your root is just "/" and applications are not installed in one folder only. A directory wine-stable can be found in /opt on my machine (look in File System).

But to start Wine you just need to open the Windows application you want to work with by doubleclicking it and all will run. Wine does not have a UI in itself, it is just a translation layer. Consult their [documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ).

Comment: In fact, there is a previous question and a more complete answer to your question, but I'm new to the forum and haven't figured out how to mark it as duplicate. Hope this helps.